# How to deserialize BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization, memory-mapped-files, binaryformatter

I'm trying to serialize my MMF to file and here is the code:

```
class MMF {
    private const string filename = @"c:\NFS";
    private long offset = 0;
    private long length = 194;
    private byte[] buffer;
    public MMF() {
        using (var mmf =
            MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, null, offset + length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute)) {
            using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute)) {
                buffer = new byte[194];
                /*FS fs = new FS();
                fs.Files[0].Path = "test";
                accessor.WriteArray<byte>(0, buffer, 0, (int)length);*/
                accessor.ReadArray<byte>(0, buffer, 0, (int)length);
                FS fs = (FS)ToObject(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine(fs.Files[0].Path);
                }
            }
        }
    private byte[] ToByteArray(object source) {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
            return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    private object ToObject(byte[] source) {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(source)) {
            formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return stream;
            }
        }
    }
```

On deserialization part I'm getting error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: A binary stream "0" does not contain a valid
>   binary header BinaryHeader. Possible causes: invalid stream or object
>   version change between serialization and deserialization.

How to Deserialize the file properly? Where is my mistake?

*thank you*

Comment: `return  formatter.Deserialize(stream);`

Comment: error is on formatter.Deserialize(stream) line level

Comment: Dump the content of the 192 bytes. Like Oded said, I suspect it is all zero's. Also nothing what `FS` actually is, would help. Also, why are you using a MMF, and not just a `FileStream`?

Comment: I want to use MMF instead FileSystem because I want to create an really virtual file system and 192 bytes is not nulls.

Comment: Without extra info, it is hard to say. It could be anything. Do you have the code online somewhere?

Comment: yes sure https://github.com/nCdy/NENFS

Comment: here https://github.com/nCdy/NENFS/blob/master/NEN_Server/FS/MMF.cs

Comment: Got this to work from your sources:
http://pastebin.com/9mB84q42

Comment: I was just going to suggest what @DmitriyReznik did. Loose `ISerializable` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to let MMF implement [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) and implement the GetObjectData method.